# Redirecting to a webpage when an error occurs in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to go to a certain page if this code has an error can anyone help me out?

I leave the catch black is there a certain code that will redirect me to my *Error Controller Index*?

```
try
{
  var tree = ViewData["data"] as IEnumerable<PrototypeHelp.Models.Treeview>;
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Comment: Your question is [ambigious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambiguous) because it's not normally possible to have an exception thrown in the razor view engine.  Typically exceptions occur in controllers or in views.  Do you mean this code is in a view?

Comment: yes its in the view im handling the viewdata if it has an error it will redirect to a certain page like i mentioned in this post. i just didnt post all the codes is there a possible way?

Comment: you should put the redirect in to your controller. How would you test your view if you put the redirect in it?

Comment: for example i have this hyperlink
`@Html.ActionLink("Help Library", "Index", "Home")` 
i just want to go to the page without clicking that hyper link is there a possible way? some sort of codes?

Comment: Have exception handling in your view because of something that can absolutely be prevented in a controller is literally bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle exception in global.asax file. this will handling exceptions in application level including page or controller.

Example code:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
  Response.Clear();

  HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

  if (httpException != null) {
    string action;

    switch (httpException.GetHttpCode()) {
      case 404:
        // page not found
        action = "HttpError404";
        break;
      case 500:
        // server error
        action = "HttpError500";
        break;
      default:
        action = "General";
        break;
      }

      // clear error on server
      Server.ClearError();

      Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?message={1}", action, exception.Message));
    }
```

Comment: ok if i did this no need to include a try catch in every code??

Comment: Yes You don't need to :)